# Repeat a function N times in Julia (composition)

Tags: julia, repeat, composition, mutable, function-composition

I'm trying to make a function that compose a function f(x) by itself N times, something like that:

```
function CompositionN(f,N)
             for i in 1:N
                f(x) = f(f(x))
             end
return f(x)
```

I need that the function CompositionN returns another function, not a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution with `ntuple` and splatting works very well up to a certain number of compositions, say 10, and then falls off a performance cliff.

An alternative solution, using `reduce`, is fast for large numbers of compositions, `n`, but comparatively slow for small numbers:

```
compose_(f, n) = reduce(∘, ntuple(_ -> f, n))
```

I think that the following solution is optimal for both large and small `n`:

```
function compose(f, n)
    function (x)  # <- this is syntax for an anonymous function
        val = f(x)
        for _ in 2:n
            val = f(val)
        end
        return val
    end
end
```

BTW: it is the construction of the composed function which is faster in the approach suggested here. The runtimes of the resulting functions seem to be identical.

Comment: Thanks! , in this way clarify me much about the composition!

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of the [`∘`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.:%E2%88%98) function, which allows you to compose multiple functions:

```
julia> composition(f, n) = ∘(ntuple(_ -> f, n)...)
composition (generic function with 1 method)

julia> composition(sin, 3)(3.14)
0.001592651569876818

julia> sin(sin(sin(3.14)))
0.001592651569876818
```

Comment: This works really well for small `n`, up to 10 on my computer. Then it suddenly becomes slow. For large `n` this seems to work better: `compose(f, n) = reduce(∘, ntuple(_ -> f, n))`.

Comment: @giordano How can I compose several functions that have as input and as output 2 variables? E.g. `f= (x,y)->(x+y,x*y); ∘(f,f,f)(1,1)` returns errors instead of `(5,6)`.

Comment: @Leo: your function composition works if it is not anonymous, but named: `f(x, y) = (x+y, x*y)`.

Comment: @JakeIreland And there's no syntax to make it work also for nameless functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach:

```js
julia> compose(f, n) = n <= 1 ? f : f ∘ compose(f, n-1)
compose (generic function with 1 method)

julia> compose(x -> 2x, 3)(1)
8
```

If we're willing to do a little type piracy, we can use the power operator `^` on functions to represent `n`-th order self-composition:

```
julia> Base.:^(f::Union{Type,Function}, n::Integer) = n <= 1 ? f : f ∘ f^(n-1)

julia> f(x) = 2x
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> (f^3)(1)
8
```

Comment: Maybe test `n<=1` to avoid stack overflow in case of negative `n`?

Comment: @DNF Good point. I've edited the answer to include that.